# R function for creating monotonic (increasing or decreasing) permutations

Tags: r, permutation

I'm trying to create an efficient function to generate all monotonically increasing permutations of a large vector.  Obviously, reducing the outputs from `expand.grid` or `gtools::permutations` works, but only for smaller vectors.

Example:

```
x = 1:3
```

Desired output:

```
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2
1, 1, 3
1, 2, 2
1, 2, 3
1, 3, 3
2, 2, 2
2, 2, 3
2, 3, 3
3, 3, 3
```

Any suggestions using base R or, existing packages with this capability?

**EDIT:** An ideal solution would avoid generating the complete set of permutations to then subset.

Comment: Can you adjust your example desired output to display a permutation of length 2 (they are all currently length 3)

Comment: The permutations need to be of `length(x)`, but an additional argument for permutation length would be an improvement!

Comment: When dealing with vectors of differing lengths, you need to think (carefully) about how you want to store them. For example, in your desired output above, would a vector of length 2 be displayed `1, 2, NA` ?

Comment: Thanks Steve, all output vectors would be of the same length according to the function argument, so I'm not sure why the 'NA' padding would be an issue.

Comment: These are not permutations. These are simply combinations with repetition in lexicographical order.

Comment: I might misunderstand what you are looking for, but It looks like you are missing a few outputs as well; `(1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (2, 2, 3)`

Comment: `arrangements` package is useful for this, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table` this is fairly easy:

```r
expand.monotonic <- function(x, len=length(x)){
    do.call(CJ, lapply(integer(len), function(...) x ))[
        eval(parse(text=paste0("V", 2:len, ">=", "V", 1:(len-1), collapse="&") )), ]
}
expand.monotonic(1:3)
   V1 V2 V3
 1:  1  1  1
 2:  1  1  2
 3:  1  1  3
 4:  1  2  2
 5:  1  2  3
 6:  1  3  3
 7:  2  2  2
 8:  2  2  3
 9:  2  3  3
10:  3  3  3
```

#### explanation:

First create a list containing the replicated vector `len` times, Use `data.table::CJ` to cross join all the vectors. And this is where the magic happens based on the `len` create an expression basically `V2>=V1&V3>=V2` as `V#` is the default name for unnamed columns, and subset by the result of evaluating said expression.

```r
parse(text=paste0("V", 2:len, ">=", "V", 1:(len-1), collapse="&") )
# expression(V2>=V1&V3>=V2)
```

Comment: This is a very good solution using `data.table`!

Comment: Thanks Abdessabour, I've edited the question to reflect the memory consideration as well.  The `data.table` solution has a larger `object.size` than the `gtools::permutations` result and both are substantially larger than the final output.

Comment: @FredViole I run through those errors when trying to benchmark, cross join eats up a lot of memory

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code which creates permutations with repeats allowed as in your example, and detects whether each permutation is monotonic

```r
x <- 1:3

# Generate permutations of length x
out <- gtools::permutations(length(x), length(x), v = x, repeats.allowed=TRUE)

# Detect if they're monotonic
mono <- apply(out, 1, function(x) { all(x == cummax(x)) })


output_with_monotonic_label <- cbind(out, mono)

# output_with_monotonic_label
#             mono
#  [1,] 1 1 1    1
#  [2,] 1 1 2    1
#  [3,] 1 1 3    1
#  [4,] 1 2 1    0
#  [5,] 1 2 2    1
#  [6,] 1 2 3    1
#  [7,] 1 3 1    0
#  [8,] 1 3 2    0
#  [9,] 1 3 3    1
# [10,] 2 1 1    0
# ....
```

Comment: Thanks, this is where I was with the problem earlier and it gets really inefficient really fast.